# Slow queries and proxysql

Tags: mysql, proxysql

I would like to use proxysql so that they can by itself redirect requests which will take too long to execute, I don't know if it's possible but I look no matter how hard I find anything.
Someone would have any idea ?

Comment: Let's discuss why the query is taking so long.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `EXPLAIN SELECT...` and the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: If I have to send all the `show create table` it’s going to be long, it’s often on a big request with many `inner join`, I’ll rather look for a solution with proxysql

Comment: The _client_ could bypass proxysql and connect to the Replica that is dedicated to long queries.

Comment: Yes it would be a solution but the problem is how to identify the queries that pose problem automatically.

Comment: Are users making up arbitrary queries?  How many Replicas do you have?